# NSDirectoryEnumerator fileAttributes is nil

Tags: ios, file, enumeration

I am trying to grab the top level directories only

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:directory]
                                         includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLIsDirectoryKey, nil]
                                                            options: NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles | NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants
                                                       errorHandler:nil];

for (NSURL *file in directoryEnumerator) {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [directoryEnumerator fileAttributes];
    if ([attributes objectForKey:NSFileType] == NSFileTypeDirectory) {
        NSLog(@"Yes its a directory");
    }
}
```

But every time I get nil for fileAttributes.  Shouldn't I be able to get fileAttributes when using an nsdirectoryenumerator?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to call `fileAttributes` on the enumerator. Instead, you want to get the desired property from the URL.

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:directory]
                                         includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLIsDirectoryKey]
                                                            options: NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles | NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants
                                                       errorHandler:nil];

for (NSURL *file in directoryEnumerator) {
    NSNumber *isDirectory;
    [url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:NULL];
    if ([isDirectory boolValue]) {
        NSLog(@"Yes its a directory");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup that works.  Still clear as mud though.  Why would I be able to get fileAttributes?  Seems like the method is there for a reason.

Comment: Why don't you want to call `fileAttributes` on the enumerator?